# How to know Realm Object Server version installed with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, realm

One way to know the version of installed realm object server is with Realm Studio.
is there another method or command line other than that?
I have root access and the web app in Nodejs v6.14.3 NPM v3.10.10
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the version of your Realm Object Server is not exposed in Realm JS. But if your server is `my-ros.example.com`, you can use `http://my-ros.example.com:9080/health`. The returned information might change in future versions so be prepared for breaking changes :-)